# How to make a reusable java function for android webview

Tags: java, android, email, webview

Please am very new to java, am trying to put my website in webview, i have few lines of code that send user to email form and is working very fine. But now i have to use the same code in more than 3 place when url match something and i know that there will be a way to put this code one place as a function then call it and time i want to use it. please can someone help me.

```
    function RequestMailForm(newbody, newsubject, newemailto, newmailbbc){
     /* That email code*/
    }
   mva.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
        url = url.substring(7);
        String body = "Body of message.";
        Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mail.setType("application/octet-stream");
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { url });
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        startActivity(mail);
        return true;
    }
    if (url.startsWith("http://example.com/help") || url.startsWith("https://example.com/contact")){
      RequestMailForm(newbody, newsubject, newemailto, newmailbbc);
    }
});
```

Comment: What hinders you from putting your code(which is supposed to be re-used) into a class?

Comment: @B001 please show me how because i also don't know how to do that, i have created a new java class for that but how do i code it to pass the new email and message body etc that i want it to

Comment: _wast of resource..._? are you talking about bytes?

Comment: @B001, sorry i edited my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class and put sendEmail method with message and email paramater.
See the code below.

```
class SendEmail {
    Context context;

    public SendEmail(Context context){
        this.context = contex;
    }

    //send an email
    public void send(String email) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto", email, null));
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of message");
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
    }
}
```

Then create an object of the `SendEmail` class and call that function every time you want to send an email like this:

```
if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
    url = url.substring(7);
    sendEmail.send(url);
    return true;
}
```